# "give away photographs"

Tags: meaning-in-context

From [BBC / Travel / Where a simple photo changed a life](http://www.bbc.com/travel/story/20160825-where-a-simple-photo-changed-a-life)

> A white-haired beggar sits outside the 13th-century Konark Sun Temple in Odisha, India, a wide smile spread across his face. His hands, deformed by leprosy, cradle the first photo of himself he has ever seen.
>
> Swapna, a young mother in Kolkata, lives in a grass hut without electricity or running water. She has no photos of her wedding, but thanks to Hollywood film editor Bipasha Shom, she owns a portrait of herself and her five-month-old son, Neeladri.
>
> These two are among hundreds of impoverished Indians that Shom has gifted with a photograph. “Many of these people are surviving on a dollar a day or less, and a photo is a luxury item,” she said. “They do not have the means to buy cameras, let alone afford to make prints.” Some have cell phones but they are very basic models, with no photo capability or with extremely low resolution images.
>
> Born in Kolkata, but raised in New Jersey, Shom, 47, was in her teens when she first began **giving away** photographs while visiting relatives in India.

Does "give away" mean shoot or just present something?

Comment: Give away as gifts.

Comment: I think the term *giving away photographs* here refers to the practice in some Asian countries, where a girl, when she reaches marriageable age will have a set of photographs made. These will be *given away* in what are considered the right social circles (often by her parents and others) in an effort to attract potential bridegrooms. I do not believe the practice is unique to females.

Comment: Many thanks. What do you think of the "while" here? A time conj. or others?

Comment: @WS2: In context, it actually seems likely to me that "giving away photographs" refers to taking photos of the *relatives* and giving these to them. The preceding passage: "*These two are among hundreds of impoverished Indians that Shom has gifted with a photograph. 'Many of these people are surviving on a dollar a day or less, and a photo is a luxury item,' she said. 'They do not have the means to buy cameras, let alone afford to make prints.' Some have cell phones but they are very basic models, with no photo capability or with extremely low resolution images.*"

Comment: @H.Sophie Perfectly normal use of *while*, introducing a time clause.

Comment: @suməlic Is this fact or supposition?

Comment: @WS2: It's a supposition, but one I'm reasonably confident of. Have you read the linked article? The first sentence is: "*A white-haired beggar sits outside the 13th-century Konark Sun Temple in Odisha, India, a wide smile spread across his face. His hands, deformed by leprosy, cradle the first **photo of himself** he has ever seen.*" From later on: "*They spent four weeks giving away hundreds of photos in Kolkata and the coastal town of Puri. While Shom **photographed people of all ages,** Manley and Black captured **her subjects gazing in awe at their photos** for the first time.*"

Comment: @suməlic Ridiculously, though it is a BBC site, it is not available to anyone in the UK since it is part of their Worldwide Service. (It is all to do with the legalities of their licensing system). Having read your extract I take your point, and offer you my apologies (and vicariously those of the BBC). However I shall not delete my answer since it would seem a perfectly valid interpretation of the single sentence we were given.

Comment: @WS2: I see! Huh, that part about the BBC is silly. Yeah, your answer makes sense based just on the sentence given.

Comment: @suməlic The BBC is financed by a license fee that it is empowered to collect from everyone who owns a TV or radio receiver in the UK. That is how it survives without reliance on advertisers etc. Most people in Britain love it that way. However in the internet age it is becoming increasingly difficult to enforce the license, as people can receive BBC programmes etc on-line. The problem we have exposed here, I feel certain, is part of their effort to defend their license. There has been a lot of talk about the BBC becoming a chargeable on-line service.

Answer (score 2):

I think the term *giving away photographs* here refers to the practice in some Asian countries, where a girl, when she reaches marriageable age will have a set of photographs made. These will be handed out in what are considered the right social circles (often by her parents and others) in an effort to attract potential bridegrooms of the 'right sort'.

I do not believe the practice is unique to females.

Nowadays it forms part of a rather modernised system of the ancient custom of arranged marriages. The following Wikipedia article refers to it.

See [Arranged Marriages on the Indian Sub-Continent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arranged_marriage_in_the_Indian_subcontinent#Exchange_of_photographs.2Finformation_with_prospective_matches) on Wikipedia

> ... The matchmaker identifies a set of potential matches and, based on mutual agreement between families, it is customary for an exchange of photographs and some documentation of the factors being considered (for instance, astrological charts or a resume/biodata) to follow. These items are usually returnable if the match does not proceed: In those scenarios, families customarily cooperate to eliminate any trace of a matchmaking conversation between them. The son/daughter reviews the information and photographs, with input from the family and friends, and shortlists a few for in-person meetings.

Comment: @NVZ  I am very glad to have my answer endorsed by someone with local knowledge. But I don't believe it to be unique to India. I have seen it used by the Japanese middle classes, and among the Overseas Chinese.

Comment: Thanks for everyone. But I think you'd better read the original news. It doesn't talk about blind date. haha...

Comment: This is interesting information, but I don't think this meaning fits with the context of the sentence, so I'm DV'ing for that reason.